# Flutter - How to scan QR code with front camera?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

i want to be able to scan QR code in my app with the front camera but all the available plugins supports only the main camera and dont have any option to capture from front cam, is there is any solution to this problem in the mainwhile?

Comment: Does this plugin help? https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_mobile_vision

Comment: doesnt support ios unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it in the options of the scan function:

```
Future scan() async {
    print("Scanning!!!");
    try {
      String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan(
        options: ScanOptions(
          useCamera: 1,
        )
      ).then((value) { return value.rawContent;});
      setState(() => this.barcode = barcode);
    }  catch (e) {
      if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.cameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          this.barcode = 'The user did not grant the camera permission!';
        });
      } else {
        setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
      }
    } 
  }
```

Using the number 1 in the useCamera property in ScanOptions means the front camera.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Which package does this use?